# WordPress - Run function on form submit

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I am trying to do the following for users on my site.

1. Give the user a chance to resend their activation email if they try to login, but have not yet activated.
2. Check that the email they enter is in the list of current users who have not yet activated

I am trying to do this via a shortcode, so the code for the page itself is contained in the following function. I have not yet written the function to check the user against the current list of users (but have that code elsewhere, and don't necessarily need that code.
I know I need an action on the form, but this is where I come up blank, and can't seem to find answers that make sense to me.

```
function resend_activation_email_form() {
echo 'Activation Email Form<br>';
echo '<form><input type="email"><br>';
echo '<button type="submit">Resend Activation Email</button></form>';
}
add_shortcode('resend_activation','resend_activation_email_form');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add action to your form and then add condition to your shortcode

```
add_shortcode('resend_activation','resend_activation_email_form'); 
$post_arr = array();
if(isset($_POST['reSendMail']))
{
$post_arr = $_POST;
}
do_shortcode('[resend_activation passdata='.$post_arr.']');
```

modified function

```
function resend_activation_email_form($attr) {
var_dump($attr);
    if(isset($attr['passdata']) && !empty($attr))
    {
        var_dump($attr);
    }
    else
    {
    echo 'Activation Email Form<br>';
    echo '<form action=""><input type="email"><br>';
    echo '<button name="reSendMail" type="submit">Resend Activation Email</button></form>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting the page to appear is not the issue. My question asks how to get a function to run on submitting the form.

Comment: after submit resend form  ??

Comment: I am using the shortcode to create the form, IE there is no separate PHP file. If I need to do this I will. Hence the reason why most of the solutions I have read do not necessarily make sense to me.

Comment: Kruti, Thanks for the push in the right direction, I followed the adding the action="" to the form and then was able to code the remainder of how the form should act.